# Remove CardView Overdraw

Tags: android, performance

I ran the 'Debug GPU Overdraw' tool on my app in an attemtp to reduce the amount of overdraw. As seen in the image below, the cardview acts like an extra layer of overdraw. I haven't given any additional background colors or images to my other layouts.

Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_profile"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/created_by"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time_ago"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/likes_logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_like_red"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/likes_product"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="123"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/container_top"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/brand_product"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name_product"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post item layout file

Comment: I edited the question and added the xml layout file

Comment: why it is so complicated? it can be reduced to somthing like [this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/5b9dde06b024c9bc617dd8a0ec9dc132)

Comment: By removing the background color of the parts above and under I got a better result. Thanks!

Comment: @Selvin I think you should post the gist as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a misconception, because this is not some "overdraw", but *hardware layers* are being displayed greenish. In case you really want to disable that, just disable the hardware acceleration for the `View` (or even the whole application, altogether):

```
cardView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I mean, you could try to disable it once to see that the greenish overlay is gone and then remove that instruction again, in order to switch the hardware acceleration back on. If it may lag, this likely has another reason; for example: a `RecyclerView` in combination with a `ScrollView` may lag dearly, when they're mis-configured.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` have a background set #fff.
Remove them and see if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had a simple CardView layout as below, with this also I was observing an overdraw on the card borders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dev_card_view"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I was able to get rid of the overdraw by setting cardElevation to 0dp

```
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Comment: It is not sollution i need to set elevation then what will i do ?